# Linear Program to Find Feasible Point

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solution-verification

> I generalize the problem to be:
>
> Let $P = \{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}: x \in \mathbb{R}^d\}$ such that we want to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$ where
>
> $$ f(x_i) := \begin{cases}
> 10x_i, ~~~x_i < 0 \\
> 100x_i, ~~~x_i \geq 0.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Further, suppose $\mathbf{A}$ unknown. Instead, for known vectors $\{\alpha_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^n$ and $\{c_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^n$ we have that
>
> $$||a_i - \alpha_i||_{\infty} \leq c_i. \tag{1}$$

A remark mentions that (1) implies $a_{ij} \in [\alpha_{ij} - c_i, \alpha_{ij} + c_i]$, and then to just define some auxiliary variables to get a linear program. This doesn't quite seem obvious to me so I tried to construct it:

$$ \begin{aligned}
 & \underset{}{\min} 
 && \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \\
 & \text{subject to}
 & & z_i \geq 10x_i \\
    &&& z_i \geq 100x_i \\
 &&& y_i \geq a_{ij} - \alpha_{ij} \\
    &&& y_i \geq \alpha_{ij} - a_{ij} \\
 &&& y_i \leq c_i \\
    &&& \mathbf{y}'\mathbf{z} \leq \mathbf{b} \\
 &&& \hspace{-1cm} -\infty < a_{ij} < \infty
 \end{aligned}
$$

For all $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Would this be a correct formulation? Specifically, I'm unsure of how I modeled $y_i$, and if this is proper:

$$y_i = ||a_i - \alpha_i||_{\infty} = \max\{|a_{ij} - \alpha_{ij}| : \forall j \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$